# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS screen blank does not respect settings

Tags: suspend, power-management, lock-screen

**OS**: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Whatever settings I make to Screen blank (never or 15 minutes) the screen goes blank after 1 minute. It's very annoying, sometimes while reading an article if I don't move the mouse or press any key it activates screen blank (it doesn't ask for password, but I have to move the mouse or press any key to get it to come back).

**My Power settings**

Automatic Suspend On Battery Power & Plugged In set to `20 minutes`

[image]

Comment: Try using dconf editor and set the desired value in `org->gnome->settings->daemon->plugins->power->sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`. At least you have an annoying setting, my one made the screen blank non-functional which caused a component in my laptops display panel to burn out. I had eventually figured out you can set `sleep-inactive-ac-type` to configure the behavior, mine was on `'nothing'` which is not a great one.

Comment: I'm on uBuntu 22.04.2 LTS and changing the recommended dconf settings do NOT affect the problem screen blanking. The blanking is immediate and occurs after 30 seconds. None of the settings are set to this value. I have selected 10 minutes for dim Screen in Settings. In dconf I have set:
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout to 7,200
sleep-inactive-ac-type to nothing
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout to 2,400
sleep-inactive-battery -type to suspend
None of the above settings change the behaviour.
This problem just started occurring in the last few days.

Comment: Since adding my comments I disabled:
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/jammy main

and then 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Now the display is staying on appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, the OP disabled the bad PPA `ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/jammy main` and ran `sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. dconf/gsettings didn't work. Now the display is staying on appropriately.